# Adding new app in iTunes connect

Tags: macos, app-store-connect

When I try to add new app in iTunes Connect I get the following message "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for Mac OS X apps. Register one here = link to the

Note:

1. I have all 3 certificates: Development, Distribution & Installer
   Distribution.
2. I do not have any applications in iTunes Connect.
3. My app don't use Store technologies such as IAP, Game Center...

What is it? Bug? Or i doing something wrong? 
Thank you!

Please don't mark my question as a duplicate. This is not duplicate! Similar question about iOS and Store technologies!

Comment: As it is smart!Down vote the question and don't leave a comment! Well done!

Comment: Did you try programmers or apple stack exchanges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the link it gives you and create a bundle id.   This is a special string that looks like a reversed domain name that is unique for each application you create.   For example, if your company is `foo.com`, you might create a bundle id

```
com.foo.myApplication
```

This is done in the Mac (or iOS) dev center under the Identifiers option.    Once you've done that, you can go back to iTunes Connect and create the application.